# How showing center text on android ?

Tags: android

I want in spin progress  showing countdown text.
but I don't know text showing center.
Perhap , how can I center text  on android ?

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_weight="2.53"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_image"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/countdown"
    android:textSize="45dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

mCount = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.countdown);
mCount.setText(mCount.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));

  @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mCount.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            }
        }
```

Comment: just set android:gravity="center" as a attribute to your textview.

Comment: Please add complete layout file code

Comment: edit your question .elaborate

Comment: Do you want the text to show up inside the ProgressBar? If so, a negative layout_marginTop in the TextView can do that for you.

Comment: if you use android:layout_weight property then your android:layout_width should be 0dp